# Class cast Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java

while compiling the code I got the above exception. The code is:

IPAMEmailManagerBean.java-

```
DAOFactory daoFactory = DAOFactory.getInstance();
PropertyDAO propertyDAO = (PropertyDAO) daoFactory.getDAO("org.hc.cbl.dao.property.PropertyDAO");
StringBuilder aaCategoryCode = new StringBuilder();
PropertyAACategoryCodesTO propertyAACategoryCodesTO = null;
List<String> ahrCategoryCodeList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(applicantSavedSearchTO.getAccHousingCatIdStr().split(",")));
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (String s : ahrCategoryCodeList)
  list.add(Long.valueOf(s));
  System.out.println(list);
  List list1 = propertyDAO.findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList1(applicantSavedSearchTO.getPartnerId(), list); //This line showing class cast exception java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long 
  if(list1!=null ){
    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
      propertyAACategoryCodesTO=(PropertyAACategoryCodesTO)list1.get(i);
      aaCategoryCode.append(propertyAACategoryCodesTO.getAaCategoryCodeDesc()+",");
    }
  }
}
```

PropertyDAO.java-

```
public List findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList1(Long partnerId, List strAHRCategoryCode)throws CBLException {
  List AHRCategoryCodesList = null;
  try {
    log.debug("Entering PropertyAACategoryCodeDAO  public List findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList()throws CBLException");
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery("from PropertyAACategoryCodesTO as propertyAACategoryCodesTO "
    + "where propertyAACategoryCodesTO.partnerTO.partnerId=:partnerId and propertyAACategoryCodesTO.aaCategoryId "
    + "in(:strPropertyTypes) order by propertyAACategoryCodesTO.aaCategoryCodeDesc asc");
    query.setLong("partnerId",partnerId);
    query.setParameter("strPropertyTypes", strAHRCategoryCode);
    query.setCacheable(true);
    AHRCategoryCodesList=query.list();
    HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
  } catch (Exception ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
  }
  log.debug("Exit PropertyAACategoryCodeDAO  public List findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList()throws CBLException");
  return AHRCategoryCodesList;
}
```

I already cast the list value as long, so what might be the cause please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you serious with your indentation .. I've never seen as bad

Comment: Look the return type of this method propertyDAO.findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList1(applicantSavedSearchTO.getPartnerId(), list);

Comment: *I already cast the list value as long, so what might be the cause* The error message is very clear `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`. You can't do this cast.

Comment: looks like `applicantSavedSearchTO.getPartnerId()` is returning a list

Comment: hi , thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is showing the exception is that PropertyDAO.findAHRCategoryCodesByPartnerIdAndCodeList1() or one of the methods it is calling is attempting to cast a List into a Long.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: If that was indeed the answer that helped you, can you please mark it as accepted? It will help me help others. Thanks!